# LazyColumn (JetpackCompose) rememberLazyListState broken if a spacer is used,

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In LazyColumn when I'm using an extra spacer the scroll state functionality (keeping the last item we launched from) doesn't seem to work, is there an additionaly property to be used or is this a bug?

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding() + 8.dp)
        ) {
            //THIS IS THE CULPRIT BELOW THIS LINE 
            item{
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
            }
            //THIS IS THE CULPRIT ABOVE THIS LINE 
            items(
                items = bakesMap.toList(),
                key = { bake -> bake.first.bakeId.toString() + bake.first.recipeName }
            ) {
.....
```

Any workarounds?
should I report this as a bug? (without the spacer everything seems fine)
compose version 1.3.3

Comment: What does it mean "is broken" ?

Comment: Broken = Doesn't work anymore, so if without spacer when you come back you are on the (let's say) 25th item, with spacer when you hit back you always get the 1st item

Comment: try assigning some key to the spacer item

Comment: assigning a unique key doesn't make a difference Jan